# How can I display a long list in three shorter columns?

Tags: php, html-table

Is there a way to modify this PHP code

```
    foreach ($categories as $category)    
    {
        print("<tr>");               
        print("<td><a href=\"category.php?category=" . $category["id"] . "\">{$category["category"]}</a></td>");            
        print("</tr>");    
    }
```

to display the content in three shorter columns instead of just one really long one? Like here http://www.registrar.fas.harvard.edu/courses-exams/courses-instruction

The display order needs to be like this:

```
1 4 7
2 5 8 
3 6 9
```

Comment: Do you want to keep it as 3 column table or you can also change HTML tags and add some CSS?

Comment: I would be inclined to use array_chunk and use 3 uls.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use 3 cell tags in each row tag:

```
$cols = 3;
$col = 0;
foreach ($categories as $category)    
{
    if($col == 0)
        print("<tr>");            
    if($col < $cols) {
        print("<td><a href=\"category.php?category=" . $category["id"] . "\">{$category["category"]}</a></td>"); 
        $col++;
    } else {
        print("</tr>");  
        $col = 0;
    }  
}
if($col != 0)
    print("</tr>");
```

Comment: Is there a way to modify this so that the entries are sorted alphabetically along the columns instead of in rows?

Comment: I've added the needed display order to my original question.

Comment: That's gonna be a little tricky.. and could be a question in itself. Or a fun learning algorithm to try and work through yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$i=1;
foreach ($categories as $category)    
{
    if($i==1) {
      print("<tr>");  
    }             
    print("<td><a href=\"category.php?category=" . $category["id"] . "\">{$category["category"]}</a></td>");  
    if($i==3) {       
       print("</tr>"); 
       $i=1; 
    }
    $i++;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will list like:

```
//    0,1,2
//    3,4,5

echo '<table><tr>';
foreach ($categories as $k=>$category){
    if($k%3==0 && $k!=0){
        echo '</tr><tr>';
    }
    echo '<td><a href="category.php?category='.$category["id"].'">'.$category["category"].'</a></td>';

}
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: I'd go with this, with the caveat that the category keys may not be integers and may not be 0 based, linear or contiguous.

Comment: There will be missing </tr> tag and some cells at the end depending on the number of elements in $categories

Comment: Is there a way to modify this so that the entries are sorted alphabetically in the columns instead of in rows?

Comment: The second one displays three really long rows.

Comment: I've added the needed display order to my original question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that $categories is an array.

```
$columns = 3;
$rows = ceil( sizeof( $categories ) / $columns );
echo "<table>\n";    
for ( $row = 1; $row <= $rows; $row++ )    
{
    echo "<tr>\n";  
    for ($column = 1; $column <= $columns; $column++) {
        $p = (($column - 1) * $rows) + $row - 1;
        $value = sizeof($categories) > $p ? $categories[$p] : '&nbsp;';
        echo "<td>{$value} {$p}</td>\n";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
 }
echo "</table>";
```

Order will be

```
1 4 7
2 5 8 
3 6 9
```